# C++ Pointer help missing arguement list use &Account::getBalance

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

im currently working on a banking system for an assignment and i have a customer with an array of accounts and im trying to output the amounts of money in each account in the array. It says i need to use a pointer i think but not sure what i would do. :s

```
double customer:: getAccounts()
{
    for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        if(Accounts[i].getBalance != 0)
        {
        double x = Accounts[i].getBalance;
        return x;
        }
    }       
}

double customer :: specAccount(int num)
{
    double x = Accounts[num].getBalance;
    return x;
}
```

error C3867: 'Account::getBalance': function call missing argument list; use '&Account::getBalance' to create a pointer to member

Comment: FYI, you can simply just `return Accounts[num].getBalance();` rather than just, temporarily, putting it in `x`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming getBalance is a method:

```
double x = Accounts[num].getBalance();
```

Or if Accounts is an array of pointers:

```
double x = Accounts[num]->getBalance();
```

Answer (score 0):

Missing parenthesis?

```
double x = Accounts[i].getBalance();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Accounts[i].getBalance != 0)
```

should be

```
if(Accounts[i].getBalance() != 0)
```

Although that is not the only problem with this code. You do the same for every call of getBalance() 
Also what happens if in the loop you don't find a balance that is !=0? You should handle that case.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't getBalance a method and so should be called like

```
Accounts[i].getBalance() ;
```

?

And if Accounts is an array of pointers, you should type

```
Accounts[i]->getBalance() ;
```

or at least

```
(*Account[i]).getBalance() ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your compiler is telling you what the problem is.  You're missing your argument list.  getBalance is a function, and functions take arguments in parentheses.  So add the parentheses, like this:

```
Accounts[i].getBalance();
```